# glTextureSubImage3D() misbehaving with small image input

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

After creating a 2D texture array with

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RED, 1024, 1024, 1, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

I upload image data portion by portion using the function glTexSubImage3D() with

```
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66, 66, 1, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The image gets uploaded but in an incorrect way. It appears to be smeared, as if it's using a different pitch instead of 66 bytes. This is on an NVIDIA card using fairly recent drivers.

Funny enough if I make the image 100 pixels wide instead (but not 99), the upload works correctly. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. OpenGL has an initial default pixel alignment of 4, even if you specify that the pixel data format is GL_RED.

By changing the row alignment to 1 byte with

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

the problem goes away.